# payu flutter android 1005

Tags: android, flutter, payu

Getting error response `flutter 1005 : server error`
after entering a credit card  details with

> merchantKey:"gtKFFx"
> merchantSalt: "4R38IvwiV57FwVpsgOvTXBdLE4tHUXFW"
> PayUPaymentParamKey.environment: "1",

after entering a card detail **payu** throwing `error 1005` but working fine in iOS